# Special characters within a GraphQL query in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, graphql, escaping, pimcore

I'm using the **[GraphQL API](https://pimcore.com/docs/data-hub/current/GraphQL/index.html)** from **Pimcore** to create Customers Objects within a simple shell script.
Everything works fine except when names or lastnames are with special characters (in spanish) like:

```
á, é, í, ó, ú, ñ
```

This is the code I'm using

```
 #!/usr/bin/env sh
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=";"
while read -r f1 f2 f3
do
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "query": "mutation { createCustomer( key:\"'${f1}'\", parentId:703, input:{ firstname:\"'${f2}'\", lastname:\"'${f3}'\"} ) { success message }}"}' http://localhost/pimcore-graphql-webservices/shop?apikey=295b86489dca91a4aafaac8315cdb84a --insecure 
done < CUSTOMERS.csv
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

Is there any way to escape those? Or maybe a better way to do it?
I've tried a lot of possibilities but couldn't make it work.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: i dont manage to do it via curl too. As an alternative, you can try via postman or node.js. https://www.contentful.com/blog/2021/01/14/GraphQL-via-HTTP-in-five-ways/

Comment: GrapthQL accepts those charactes with no problems, I tested. So it is only question for SH script + Curl how to send UTF-8 string.